# ASP.net customized routing with Action/Id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to change the routing for my website for the past few hours and I just can't find out what ASP.net wants from me!

This is my default routing:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, }
        );
```

It successfully brings up Home/Index whenever I go to these URLs:

```
/
/Home
/Home/Index
```

However, I have an action called "K" like below which receives a parameter "name":

```
public ActionResult K(string name)
```

I want to define a route that will redirect me to `/Home/K/{name}` with this template:

```
website.com/K/{name}
```

I tried this route below but It doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "OnlyK",
            "K/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "K", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also even without this route config, if I go to `website.com/Home/K/something` It will not recognize "something" as id (controller parameter == null)!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url `website.com/Home/K/something` results in a `null` value for argument `name` in the `K` action method `ActionResult K(string name)` because the argument names don't match.
This method is being served via the the route `Default`, which 
declares a parameter with name `id` (via `{controller}/{action}/{id}`), whereas action method `K` has an argument named `name`.

You can solve this by overruling the argument name on the action method, via the `BindAttribute` so that both match.

```
ActionResult K([Bind(Prefix ="id")] string name)
```

---

To do a redirect from `website.com/K/{name}` to `website.com/Home/K/{name}` you can set up a custom `IRouteHandler` that takes care of this redirect.

Register a route that handles any request that match route `K/{id}` and redirect these to a route with a wellknown name (here: `K`).
*Because of the argument name mismatch discussed about we'll use `{id}` instead of `{name}` in our routes.*

```
routes.Add(new Route("K/{id}", new RedirectRouteHandler("K")));
```

Define this route `K` as below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "K",
    url: "Home/K/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "K", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The `RouteHandler` and `RedirectHandler` doing the redirect.
The `HttpResponse` class has a `RedirectToRoute` method that can deal with route names and route values, without having to construct urls ourselves.

```
class RedirectRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private readonly string _routeName;

    public RedirectRouteHandler(string routeName)
    {
        _routeName = routeName;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new RedirectHandler(this._routeName, requestContext.RouteData.Values);
    }
}

class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private readonly string _routeName;
    private readonly RouteValueDictionary _routeValues;

    public RedirectHandler(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        this._routeName = routeName;
        this._routeValues = routeValues;
    }

    public bool IsReusable { return false; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.RedirectToRoute(this._routeName, this._routeValues);
    }
}
```

Note that the order of the registered routes matters; `RegisterRoutes` looks like.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(new Route("K/{id}", new RedirectRouteHandler("K")));

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "K",
        url: "Home/K/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "K", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```